# Why Google PlacesService or Geocode not saving the result inside function?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to pass, variable a value in `findPlaceFromQuery()`. But it not passing the value. Instead my function return the initialized value. I try google my self, but I got no solution of this. It is very common to get value in others functions but here it is not possible. I done this many time, but it is not working inside `findPlaceFromQuery()` . Also it did't work for Geocode.

in `getZone()` function at the end of script there is a variable name `check`. I have set his value to 'none' as default. And want to set and return value of `check` in `findPlaceFromQuery()`. Please help me. I am so much stuck in this.

Also please suggest me if I can do this with Google Autocomplete.

Here is my javascript code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = initializeMap;
var map, geocoder, originInput, destinationInput, originLatLng, destinationLatLng;
function initializeMap() {
  // var infoWindow;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}


function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  //var via1Input = document.getElementById('via1-input');
  destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var waypoint1 = document.getElementById('waypoint1');
  var waypoint2 = document.getElementById('waypoint2');
  var waypoint3 = document.getElementById('waypoint3');
 // var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  var waypoint1Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(waypoint1);
  var waypoint2Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(waypoint2);
  var waypoint3Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(waypoint3);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
//   console.log(originAutocomplete);
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'types']);

  var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
  // console.log(destinationAutocomplete);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'types']);
//   waypoint1Autocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);
//   waypoint2Autocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);
//   waypoint3Autocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
//   this.setupPlaceChangedListener(waypoint1Autocomplete, 'DEST');
//   this.setupPlaceChangedListener(waypoint2Autocomplete, 'DEST');
//   this.setupPlaceChangedListener(waypoint3Autocomplete, 'DEST');

}


AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
    autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
     
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    }
//   console.log(me);

    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;


  var waypts = [];

  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");

if(waypoint1.value != ''){
    waypts.push({
      location: waypoint1.value,
      stopover: true
    });
}

if(waypoint2.value != ''){

    waypts.push({
      location: waypoint2.value,
      stopover: true
    });
}

if(waypoint3.value != ''){

    waypts.push({
      location: waypoint3.value,
      stopover: true
    });
}

//console.log(waypts);

  this.directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
        destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: this.travelMode
      },
      function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
};

var waypoint = 0;
function addVia()
{
  waypoint++;
  $('#via-'+waypoint).show();
  $('#vialabel-'+waypoint).show();
  //this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  if(waypoint == 3)
  {
    $('#addvia').hide()
  }

}

function onDestinationChange(data)
{
    
    var pickupLocation = getZone(originInput.value);
    
    var destinationLocation = getZone(destinationInput.value);

  

    setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    console.log(pickupLocation);
    
    if(pickupLocation)
              {
                  jQuery.ajax({
                     url : '/calculateroutecost',
                     type : "POST",
                     data : {_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', pickupLocation:pickupLocation, destinationLocation:destinationLocation},
                     dataType : "json",
                     success:function(data)
                     {
                        // alert("SUCCESS");
                        alert(data.success);
                     }
                  });
              }
              else
              {
                  alert("Please add a pickup location.");
              }
    
  }, 3000);
    


}

         
$("#booking-cost").submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action

var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url

var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method

var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission



$.ajax({

url : post_url,

type: request_method,

data : form_data

}).done(function(response){ 




});

});

         
var iii = 0;

function getZone(pAddress) {
    var myLatLng, pickupLatLng, check = 'none', result;
    const zoneCoords = {!! json_encode($json) !!};
    const outerCoords = zoneCoords['outer'];
    const innerCoords = zoneCoords['inner'];
   
    const zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [outerCoords, innerCoords]
  });
  const request = {
    query: pAddress,
    fields: ["geometry"]
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      pickupLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      result = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
      pickupLatLng,
      zone
      )
        ? check = 'yes'
        : check = 'no';
      return check;
    }
    return check;
  });
    // var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // var address = pAddress;
    // var myLoc;
    // var latlng = [];
    // var output; 
    // geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    
    //   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //     myLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    //     latlng[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    //     latlng[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    //     output = latlng[0] + ', ' + latlng[1];
    //     return myLoc;
    //   } 
    // }); 
    return check;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use places autocomplete, you would eventually have a conflict of interest. Reason being, autocomplete is used in tandem with place details and not with find place. And the cost of the Find Place SKU is similar to the amount of both Autocomplete and Place Details SKU combined. See the [pricing sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/) for your reference.

The below code makes use of [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) with [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get-place-information) and [Directions API service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests).

The Place Details includes the **setFields** optional parameter to only get the data that you need, so that you won't be billed for any data that you won't use. You can learn more on how this is implemented [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields). And refer [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields) for the list of available fields.

Here is the link for the below code:https://jsfiddle.net/pintsik999/pky8a964/2/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!--Replace the key placeholder with your actual API Key-->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initializeMap&&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="origin" type="textbox">
      <input id="destination" type="textbox">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Get Directions">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var map, selected_origin, selected_destination;
function initializeMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  //Call the function for the autocomplete and place details service
  new AutocompleteHandler();
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        DirectionsHandler();
  });
}

function AutocompleteHandler() {
    //Learn more about Places Autocomplete here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete
  const originInput = document.getElementById("origin");
  const destinationInput = document.getElementById("destination");
  var autocomplete_origin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  var autocomplete_destination =   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
  //add .setfields so that you will only get the data that you need to prevent additional costs 
  //Here is the list of available fields that you can use: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields
  autocomplete_origin.setFields(["formatted_address"]);
  autocomplete_destination.setFields(["formatted_address"]);
  // Set a listener to the autocomplete to get the details of the selected place
  //learn more about how to get the place information here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get-place-information
  autocomplete_origin.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    selected_origin = autocomplete_origin.getPlace();
  });   
  autocomplete_destination.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    selected_destination = autocomplete_destination.getPlace();
  });
}

function DirectionsHandler(){
    // Learn more about the Directions Service here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route(
    {
      origin: {
        query: selected_origin.formatted_address
      },
      destination: {
        query: selected_destination.formatted_address
      },
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    (response, status) => {
      if (status === "OK") {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

If you are also trying to make use of a browser's geolocation service with google maps API, you can refer here for [HTML 5 Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)